# Separate controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and was experimenting with the code. The thing what I don't get is how to make separate modules. For example, I want to have a module for all the user functions such as login, register, forgot password etc.

I can't find a proper tutorial to learn how to do this. Can someone help me?

I have this in my **app.js**:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.submit = function(){
    var link = 'http://nikola-breznjak.com/_testings/ionicPHP/api.php';

    $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
      $scope.response = res.data;
    });
  };
});
```

And this at my **html**:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content padding="true">
          <form ng-submit="submit()">
              <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter username" ng-model="data.username">
              </label>

              <input class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit to server">
          </form>

          <div class="card">
              <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                  Response: <b ng-bind="response"></b>
              </div>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Edit (What I think it should be):

My **app.js**:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','login'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

My **usersController.js**:

```
var app = angular.module("login", []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://nikola-breznjak.com/_testings/ionicPHP/api.php';

        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });
    };
});
```

I include the **userController.js** at my html.

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules

Comment: check my answer if that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily modularize the code as:

**Step1**: Define all your module as dependencies in your main module definition

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'starter.login',
    'starter.register',
    'starter.forgot_password',
    //and any other module you want to add
])
```

**Step2:** Define these modules separately

```
//note these can be in same files or separate files all together

angular.module('starter.login',[
     'starter.login.services', //sub module for services
     'starter.login.directives', //sub module for directives
  ]);
angular.module('starter.register',[]);
angular.module('starter.forgot_password',[]);

//you can further create submodules for above modules
//eg: sub module for directive, sub module for service etc as
```

**Step3:** You can then define separately controllers/services/factories/directives for these modules.

```
//giving example for just login controller
 angular.module('starter.login').controller(function($scope){
      //note this module must be defined first before using it with a controller. so files must be loaded in the right order
});

   //similarly you will have to define your sub-modules before using them with services/controllers or directives
```

For more details you can read this very well written blog:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/

and follow John Papa's guidelines for structuring your directory:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules

Comment: Do you need 'starter.' as a prefix when you defining a module? Or can I just create a module with the module name?

Comment: you can give any name. Just that you can follow the 'parentmoduleName.' thing as a convention to make the code maintainable and understandable. When it comes to large applications having a lot of js files (controllers/services/directives), it is a good practice to follow a convention.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I have edited my code based on yours. Can you check it if I understand it correctly?

Comment: I think that is fine. But for better readability, you should really follow the convention

Comment: One more question. What do you mean with convention? A base module name? Such as user.login, user.register, user.forgot etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118751/discussion-between-rahul-arora-and-da1lbi3).

Comment: @RahulArora answer is correct and is according to best practice.

Comment: @JorawarSingh: I am glad I could contribute